# Kubernetes service not routing UDP traffic with AWS network loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, udp, nlb, aws-networking

I have set up a network load balancer on UDP port 8125, which is associated with a target group. The target group is linked to a Kubernetes service that exposes UDP port 8125, and all the pods in the target group are healthy.

When I access the UDP 8125 service from within the cluster, it works fine, and the service pods receive the requests. However, when I try to access it using the IP or DNS of the AWS network load balancer, the traffic is not routed to the service pods. Even though the target group passes all the health checks and the pods are healthy, the load balancer doesn't forward the UDP requests.

Additional information:

1. DNS resolution is working correctly, and it resolves to the IP of the network load balancer.
2. The service is accessible and functioning properly on UDP port 8125 when accessed from within the cluster.
3. I have also tried using ingress routing, but it didn't resolve the issue.
4. I attempted to expose the service as a load balancer with service annotations to create a network load balancer, set up health checks, listener ports, etc.
5. I don't see any access logs in the load balancer's access logs bucket.
6. I used the `netcat` command to check if port 8125 is open, and it returned "OK," indicating no access issues.

I have tried various troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.